# Did I install Ubuntu with Windows dual-boot correctly?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, multi-boot, grub

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 to my laptop which is running Windows 10 so they are both dual-bootable. Now, when I turn on my machine, the GRUB menu shows:

> Ubuntu
>
> Advanced options for Ubuntu
>
> Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda1)
>
> System Setup

Selecting `Ubuntu` starts Ubuntu and selecting `Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda1)` starts Windows, but on all the tutorials and videos I followed, their GRUB menus showed:

> Windows 10

Not

> Windows Boot Manager

**Question**:

Have I done something wrong or this an issue? And why did this happen?

Comment: You did nothing wrong because everything is working as expected. Actually the name "Windows Boot Manager" is the typical one. Grub menus showing "Windows 10" were probably edited to the effect. There's absolutely no need to do that.

Comment: You installed Windows first and Linux last! That was the right thing to do! (Windows has a tendency to overwrite any boot loaders that already exist, while most flavors of Linux have a tendency to respect the existing system software.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you installed it the right way!
You probably need to customize your GRUB. See how you do it [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/532415).

This happens because when you're installing Ubuntu (or other distro) it will then always boot to GRUB and defaults Windows entry as Windows Boot Manager.

Comment: Whilst agreeing with the premise of correct installation, the rest of your answer is outdated because only applicable to Legacy (BIOS) installs. In modern UEFI based systems, **the "Windows bootloader" is NOT replaced by Grub**, both co-exist in the EFI system partition and both can be booted independently via the UEFI boot menu. Quite different from the old BIOS systems where only one bootloader could be used and residing in the MBR.

Comment: @MichaelBay thanks for the tip! I never used dual-boot UEFI systems so I answered what I knew about the legacy BIOS. Feel free to add more info covering UEFI based systems

Comment: For reference: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI and https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi

Comment: @MichaelBay I mean, it will not replace the Windows bootloader but Ubuntu will force you to GRUB, no? Yeah, if you go to the UEFI boot menu I can boot right away for Windows. Anyways, thanks for the advice!

Comment: Ubuntu depends on a bootloader that *typically* is Grub. So, Grub always boots before the rest of Ubuntu whether or not it present the Grub menu.